# Read body as it is from Camel request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-camel

i am getting a request via camel route.
i need to validate the request against a X.509 Certificate.
I need to use request body in signature data.

The problem is , when i read the request body as string, the format is getting changed.

```
        String reqBody=exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```

The postman request body sent like below in JSON format

```
{"channel_id":"channel test"}
```

the body received at server side is

```
{"channel_id"="channel test"}
```

Due to change in format, my x509 validation is failing.
How to read the body string as it is from an camel exchange?
I can not convert to POJO and use toString() as the format is very sensitive, wanted to read as is.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Could it be that you are using camel's REST DSL and you don't have rest binding mode set to JSON "bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)" and thus the body is actually a map?

Comment: Bindingmode is set to json. No luck

Answer (score 0):

The binding mode changed to dataformat pretty text. This worked